# How to remove text that does not contain spaces from a delimited string in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a string such as `brown,Ceilings,flu,hydraulic bar stool,horse saddles,marble tiles`. I want to remove the text that does not contain spaces, but keep the text that has at least one space. The result should be like `hydraulic bar stool,horse saddles,marble tiles`.

I'm stuck at `[^,]*\s` and still don't know how to figure out the problem. How can I do this with a regex find and replace?

Comment: What have you tried? What did you Google? Super User is not a script writing service. People will be more likely to help you if you have something to go off of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find

```
(?<! )\b[^, ]+(,|$)
```

Replace with nothing.

How it works:

`\b[^, ]+` matches entire words.
`(?<! )` limits these matches to words that are not preceded by a space.
`(,|$)` further limits the matches to words that are followed by a comma or the end of the line.

This should match all single-word entries and the trailing comma.

Comment: to save anyone else having to google, `\b` marks the beginning or end of a word.